# What is the difference between Views and With ... as clause in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, sql-view

My example is inspired by Oracle site 
[CREATE VIEW](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj15446.html)

```
-- ex1
with SAMP_V1 as (
    AS SELECT COMM + BONUS as COL_SUM, COMM - BONUS as COL_DIFF
    FROM SAMP.EMPLOYEE) 
select * from SAMP_V1;

-- ex2
CREATE VIEW SAMP.V1 (COL_SUM, COL_DIFF)
    AS SELECT COMM + BONUS, COMM - BONUS
    FROM SAMP.EMPLOYEE;

select * from SAMP.V1;
```

The only difference I notice is that ex1 is written with one statement, while ex2 is split into two.
Also, I can use WITH to select subset of entire set, but I can do it with VIEW too.

Can it be that:

- WITH does select work only once and
- VIEW is an alias, hence it repeats SELECT every time it is mentioned

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `view` and a `with` clause are certainly not the same thing.

A `with` clause generates an inline table (aka derived table) that exists only in the query within which it executes.

On the other hand, a `view` is a legitimate database object, that, in a sense, emulates a table. A view is defined by a sql query, so it is a virtual table, that can be queried just like any other database table. Under certain conditions, you can even run DML operations or views (update, delete, insert), that are applied to the underlying tables.

If you will repeativly need the same `with` clause, then a view is helpful to shorten your queries.

Comment: What if my DB-admin denies me, for various legitimate reasons, "write" rights? Which one is preferable?